# Run python script with telnet

Tags: python, telnet

I'm using localhost to testing python scripts and I need to test it via telnet, where I'm using PuTTY. I have this python script:

```
@app.route('/add/', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into entries (title, text) values (?, ?)',
                 ("value_from_telnet", "another_value_from_telnet"))
    db.commit()
    print("Saved")
    return "Saved"
```

And now I don't know how to connect to 127.0.0.1/add and how put values into POST method. I can't use connection like this:

```
$ o 127.0.0.1/add
```

And if I try this:

```
$ o 127.0.0.1
$ GET / HTTP/1.0
$ Host: 127.0.0.1/add
```

then the result is 404 NOT FOUND (via browser it works, but only with static insert values and GET method). So I would like to ask how can I connect to this address 127.0.0.1/add and get values into POST method to use them as insert values to the database? Thank you

Comment: I belive you can do it with telnet. You just probably forgot about adding trailing slash: `$ Host: 127.0.0.1/add/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use curl instead : `curl -v -X POST 'http://<ip.address.of.server>/add' --data "title=foo&text=baz and spam and eggs"`

for a post in telnet you need to specify the body of the request like this :

```
POST /add HTTP/1.1
Content-type:application/x-http-form-urlencoded

title=foo&text=baz+and+spam+and+eggs
```

If you want to build a query string from a dictionary you need urllib

```
import urllib

params = {title:"foo",text:"baz and spam and eggs"}

print """
POST /add HTTP/1.1
Content-type:application/x-http-form-urlencoded

""",urlencode(params)
```

Comment: Sorry but I need to use telnet. It is our homework and telnet is a condition

Comment: Great, now it works. But I have one question, it works only with static insert values. What should I put instead ("value_from_telnet", "another_value_from_telnet") to take values from POST body (title and text values)?

Comment: Thanks for edit but I thought something like that:     db.execute('insert into entries (title, text) values (?, ?)',
                 (request.form["title"], request.form["text"])) but I'm just getting 400 BAD REQUEST. So what should be instead request.form["title"] to get value foo from variable title or value baz and spam and eggs from variable text? But I don't want to use any form. I'm using Flask framework.

Comment: here you have a full sample, you need to specify content-length, the size in bytes of the request body http://pastebin.com/wZw8B6vX